# Getting bound data without d3 info when using Force Layout

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code to handle double taps...

```
var onClick = function (e) {
    if ((d3.event.timeStamp - last) < 500) {
        return callback(e);
    }
    last = d3.event.timeStamp;
};
```

But this returns...

```
{
  "uuid":"e2befb22-849b-4b56-91b4-8c297311491b",
  "title":"JRG-024",
  "weight":3,
  "x":-4120.238083042915,
  "y":2759.9261895569307,
  "px":-4102.444457966419,
  "py":2753.0045790866943
}
```

Notice the `x,y,px,py, etc` I want to avoid these and get the clean data that was originally bound. I also tried `return callback(d3.select(this).data()[0])` but this still returns the location data. Is there a way to remove this data from the response, short of filtering?

Comment: Not officially documented, but I think `__data__` or  `__datum__`

Comment: Can't seem to fins an example can you give me one

Comment: NM something else was hosed that seems to work but includes the location still `d3.select(this).property("__data__")`

Comment: The force layout modifies the original data, so if you want to access it later you need to store it in separate attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on my comment

```
d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('.data')
    .data([10,20,30])
  .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'data');

var node = d3.select('.data').node();

console.log(node.__data__);
```

The console output is `10`

Comment: Right because you are not using a force directed diagram. I think you need a tick before you see the rest. I will note the original question to make this more clear.

Comment: For force-directed layouts the properties are added directly to the elements in the nodes array. They'll even overwrite values for those properties that you have set. Your only option is to manually exclude them when you display/copy, etc., but note that they'll still exist on the array objects.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't really work for me because I am not always sure which properties were added (think some are circles some are g). And this can be any type of node so I need all properties and can not filter only the ones I need.

Comment: The added properties are [documented](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#nodes).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just putting everything in a property and passing it like that. Something similar to this...

```
var d3Data = data.map(function(item){
  var result = {
    ...
    originalData : item
  }
  return result
})
```

Not accepting because it is hacky hacky hacky.